# Is there any documentation for the mouse scroll event escape sequences?

Tags: c, shell, vim, terminal, command-line

Here is a simple program so that you can see what I mean:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define ENABLE_ALT_SCREEN "\x1b[?1049h"
#define DISABLE_ALT_SCREEN "\x1b[?1049l"
#define ENABLE_ALT_SCREEN_SZ 8
#define DISABLE_ALT_SCREEN_SZ ENABLE_ALT_SCREEN_SZ
/* https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Mouse-Tracking */
#define ENABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING "\x1b[?1000h"
#define DISABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING "\x1b[?1000l"
#define ENABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING_SZ 8
#define DISABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING_SZ ENABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING_SZ

struct termios orig_termios;

void
disable_raw_mode (void)
{
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &orig_termios);
  write(STDIN_FILENO, DISABLE_ALT_SCREEN,DISABLE_ALT_SCREEN_SZ);
  write(STDIN_FILENO, DISABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING, DISABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING_SZ);  
}

void
enable_raw_mode (void)
{
  write(STDIN_FILENO, ENABLE_ALT_SCREEN,ENABLE_ALT_SCREEN_SZ);
  write(STDIN_FILENO, ENABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING, ENABLE_MOUSE_TRACKING_SZ);  
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &orig_termios);
  atexit(disable_raw_mode);

  struct termios raw = orig_termios;
  raw.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | INPCK | PARMRK | INLCR | IGNCR | ISTRIP | ICRNL | IXON);
  //  raw.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
  raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
  raw.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
  raw.c_cflag |= (CS8);


  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &raw);
}

int
main (void)
{
  enable_raw_mode();
  
  char c;
  while ( read(STDIN_FILENO,  &c, 1) == 1 && c != 'q')
    {
      if (iscntrl(c))
        printf("%d\n", c);
      else
        printf("%d ('%c')\n", c, c);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Notably, if you run `script` and then `vim`, and you scroll, none of the mouse escape sequences here are present. I am trying to catch mouse scroll events for my text editor similar to how `vim` does so.

By non-deterministic, I mean that on a scroll event (down) the terminal will send `\x1b[MaXX` where `X` varies in encoding. Likewise, for mouse scroll event (up) it will send `` \x1b[M`XX ``, where `X` varies in encoding.

Is there any documentation or knowledge that anyone has on these encodings that are sent back, how to interpret them, and the different mouse modes present [here](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Mouse-Tracking) and how to use them?

There is also a document [here](https://www.x.org/docs/xterm/ctlseqs.pdf), but its contents disagree with what I am witnessing.

To avoid being quoted an X-Y problem: I am simply trying to catch scroll events via the mouse to handle them properly in my text editor with a TUI interface. I am not using `libcurses`.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you already pointed out is quite extensive and
include all the info you need
https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

I mainly tried the hard way to collect all the info about mouse events.
I made a [script](https://github.com/ceccopierangiolieugenio/pyTermTk/blob/main/tests/test.input.raw.py) to test different terminals and different escape sequences:
In the end the documentation you already found in
https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

I recently made a [Terminal Emulator](https://ceccopierangiolieugenio.github.io/pyTermTk/info/features/widgets.html#specialised-widgets) using [pyTermTk](https://github.com/ceccopierangiolieugenio/pyTermTk) and I had to deal with the different terminal sequences related to the mouse input;

What I found so far is that there are 2+ ways the terminal return the mouse events

Those are the main sequences used to enable the mouse tracking:

```
"\033[?1000h" # Send Mouse X & Y on button press and release.
              # Report the Mouse [Press/Release,Wheel] events

"\033[?1002h" # Use Cell Motion Mouse Tracking, xterm.
              # Report the Mouse [Press/Release,Wheel,Drag] events

"\033[?1003h" # Use All Motion Mouse Tracking, xterm.
              # Report the Mouse [Press/Release,Wheel,Drag,Move] events
```

Those sequences are used to define the format the tracking is returned:
(Note: The UTF-8 Mode seems enabled by default)
https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Extended-coordinates

- "**\033[?1005h**" # Enable UTF-8 Mouse Mode, xterm.
  i.e.

  > '\x1b[MC\x95('

  ```
  UTF-8 (1005)
     This enables UTF-8 encoding for Cx and Cy under all tracking
     modes, expanding the maximum encodable position from 223 to
     2015.  For positions less than 95, the resulting output is
     identical under both modes.  Under extended mouse mode,
     positions greater than 95 generate "extra" bytes which will
     confuse applications which do not treat their input as a UTF-8
     stream.  Likewise, Cb will be UTF-8 encoded, to reduce
     confusion with wheel mouse events.

     Under normal mouse mode, positions outside (160,94) result in
     byte pairs which can be interpreted as a single UTF-8
     character; applications which do treat their input as UTF-8
     will almost certainly be confused unless extended mouse mode
     is active.

     This scheme has the drawback that the encoded coordinates will
     not pass through luit(1) unchanged, e.g., for locales using
     non-UTF-8 encoding.
  ```
- "**\033[?1006h**" # Enable SGR Mouse Mode, xterm.
  i.e.

> '\033[<35;110;11M'

```
SGR (1006)
      The normal mouse response is altered to use

      o   CSI < followed by semicolon-separated

      o   encoded button value,

      o   Px and Py ordinates and

      o   a final character which is M  for button press and m  for
          button release.

      The encoded button value in this case does not add 32 since
      that was useful only in the X10 scheme for ensuring that the
      byte containing the button value is a printable code.

      o   The modifiers are encoded in the same way.

      o   A different final character is used for button release to
          resolve the X10 ambiguity regarding which button was
          released.

      The highlight tracking responses are also modified to an SGR-
      like format, using the same SGR-style scheme and button-
      encodings.
```

- "**\033[?1015h**" # Enable urxvt Mouse Mode.

  ```
  URXVT (1015)
     The normal mouse response is altered to use

     o   CSI followed by semicolon-separated

     o   encoded button value,

     o   the Px and Py ordinates and final character M .

     This uses the same button encoding as X10, but printing it as
     a decimal integer rather than as a single byte.

     However, CSI M  can be mistaken for DL (delete lines), while
     the highlight tracking CSI T  can be mistaken for SD (scroll
     down), and the Window manipulation controls.  For these
     reasons, the 1015 control is not recommended; it is not an
     improvement over 1006.
  ```

For my [tool](https://github.com/ceccopierangiolieugenio/pyTermTk) I personally use the SGR mode because it report the position as decimal and it reduce the risk of misinterpret some Cx/Cy values as some UTF-8 control sequences.

**Fun Fact:**
When I was writing my terminal emulator,
I notced that a tool I was using didn't disabled the SGR Mode from the session,
anytime I ran vim after this the mouse was not working, because vim accepts only the UTF-8 mouse mode.

you can easily reproduce this issue it with:

```
 echo -e "\033[?1006h"
 vim
```